# FFmpeg filter_complex says filter not connected to source

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to understand the how FFmpeg's filtergraph works with the help of the **graph2dot** utility ([FFmpeg graph2dot tool](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21017/ffmpeg-graph2dot-tool)).

I am using an example from one of the questions previously posted here ([How to concatenate clips from the same video with ffmpeg](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10396/how-to-concatenate-clips-from-the-same-video-with-ffmpeg/10401?newreg=50e21837bd6c4e39b140e42229104e32)). Upon trying to parse the following filtergraph which is adapted from the accepted answer,

`echo "nullsrc[vid];anullsrc[aud];[vid]trim=60:65,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[aud]atrim=60:65,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[vid]trim=120:125,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[aud]atrim=120:125,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[out];[out]nullsink" | graph2dot`

I get the following error with FFmpeg (ver 3.4):

```
[Parsed_nullsrc_0 @ 0x55cd2c952240] size:320x240 rate:25/1 duration:-1.000000 sar:1/1
[Parsed_trim_2 @ 0x55cd2c953500] Setting 'start' to value '60'
[Parsed_trim_2 @ 0x55cd2c953500] Setting 'end' to value '65'
[Parsed_setpts_3 @ 0x55cd2c953fc0] Setting 'expr' to value 'PTS-STARTPTS'
[Parsed_atrim_4 @ 0x55cd2c954f20] Setting 'start' to value '60'
[Parsed_atrim_4 @ 0x55cd2c954f20] Setting 'end' to value '65'
[Parsed_asetpts_5 @ 0x55cd2c955960] Setting 'expr' to value 'PTS-STARTPTS'
[Parsed_trim_6 @ 0x55cd2c9568c0] Setting 'start' to value '120'
[Parsed_trim_6 @ 0x55cd2c9568c0] Setting 'end' to value '125'
[Parsed_setpts_7 @ 0x55cd2c957120] Setting 'expr' to value 'PTS-STARTPTS'
[Parsed_atrim_8 @ 0x55cd2c957fa0] Setting 'start' to value '120'
[Parsed_atrim_8 @ 0x55cd2c957fa0] Setting 'end' to value '125'
[Parsed_asetpts_9 @ 0x55cd2c9587a0] Setting 'expr' to value 'PTS-STARTPTS'
[Parsed_concat_10 @ 0x55cd2c9596c0] Setting 'n' to value '2'
[Parsed_concat_10 @ 0x55cd2c9596c0] Setting 'v' to value '1'
[Parsed_concat_10 @ 0x55cd2c9596c0] Setting 'a' to value '1'
Input pad "default" with type video of the filter instance "Parsed_trim_6" of trim not connected to any source
```

As far as I understand, the `"Parsed_trim_6"` filter is connected to the source `nullsrc[vid]`.

Can anyone help me understand what's wrong here and how I can fix it?

**EDIT**: Following Mulvya's hints, the correct solution is given below:

`echo "nullsrc,split=2[vid1][vid2];anullsrc,asplit=2[aud1][aud2];[vid1]trim=60:65,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[aud1]atrim=60:65,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[vid2]trim=120:125,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[aud2]atrim=120:125,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];[v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa];[outv]nullsink,[outa]anullsink" | graph2dot`

Other lessons I learnt from this

- Video and audio streams require separate sinks. Even with the concat filter, I wasn't able to merge them into the `[out]` destination as I had originally done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consume a filter generated stream only once, unlike streams from `-i` inputs. Since `[vid]` is already supplied to the first trim `60:65`, it can't be reused. You can add a split and supply a copy to each:

```
nullsrc,split=2[vid1][vid2]; ... [vid1]trim=60:65, ... [vid2]trim=120:125, ...
```

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't clear from the documentation that nullsink could be used only once. I have added the complete solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a shell script that uses fzf to create repls from linux commands: https://github.com/vapniks/fzfrepl
There's an example in the Readme.org that shows how you can use it with ffmpeg, graph2dot & graph-easy to get a live preview diagram of the ffmpeg filtergraph thats entered at the prompt.
This could be useful for debugging filtergraphs.